# How to solve for $x$ in the following equation?

Tags: factorial

Solve for $x \in \Bbb R$, given $$(x+m)^m-\binom{m}{1} (x+m-1)^m+\binom{m}{2}(x+m-2)^m + \cdots  + (-1)^m \binom{m}{m} x^m=m!$$

Comment: If you're wondering that why did I answer my own question, see this - [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an Identity! Therefore, this is true $ \forall x \in \mathbb R$.  I came to know about this today, that's why I am sharing this with you all. Let's prove this :

Let's find coefficient of $y^m$ in $e^{xy}(e^y-1)^m$.

Expanding $(e^y-1)^m$ through binomial in LHS and Taylor series of $e^y$ in RHS, we've $$\text{Coefficient of } y^m \; \text{in} \; e^{xy}\left(e^{my}-\binom{m}{1} e^{(m-1)y}+\binom{m}{2} e^{(m-2)y}-\ldots (-1)^m\binom mm\right)=\text{Coefficient of } y^m \; \text{in} \; e^{xy} \left [ \left(1+y + \frac{y^2}{2!} +\ldots \right)-1\right]^m $$

Cancelling out $e^{xy}$ both the sides we get -

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{(x+m)^m-\binom{m}{1} (x+m-1)^m+\binom{m}{2}(x+m-2)^m \ldots (-1)^m \binom{m}{m} x^m=m!}}$$

Comment: What is the purpose of this question, if you post the answer at the same time?

Comment: @Bumblebee See this [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and also [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: I have seen this policy before. But my intention is, if you post your own answer as the same time you post the your question, it discourage people to post their answers.

Comment: @Bumblebee What if someone doesn't know how to solve a question, and is lazy to type attempt,  (in their question) or doesn't have any, he/she may pretend to know the solution, and therefore don't post any solution, till they get one. I don't want to encourage *this*. Also, if it is not good to do so, why do we have a checkbox for "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"

Comment: How do you know this without given any chance?

Comment: I have zillions of questions that I know the answer. So I can post all of them here?

Comment: Yes, you may, infact you'll earn reputation, if it is liked by community. (upvotes on your answer and question)

Comment: @JaideepKhare: Yes, I can do it, if my purpose of asking questions is earning reputations.

Comment: @Bumblebee So what? It's not bad to earn more reputation. We always answer questions in order to earn reputation.

Comment: How did you write your final step

Comment: @user471651 in LHS, write Taylor expansion of each of the $m$ terms, and then look at the coefficient of $y^m$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different variation  on the proof that was given by
OP. Introduce

$$P(x) = \sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^q {m\choose q} (x+m-q)^m.$$

We evaluate

$$[x^p] P(x)$$

where clearly $0\le p\le m.$ We have the claim if this is zero
for $p\gt 0$ and $m!$ for $p=0.$

Extracting the coefficient yields

$$\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^q {m\choose q} {m\choose p} (m-q)^{m-p}
=  {m\choose p}
\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^q {m\choose q} (m-q)^{m-p}
\\ =  {m\choose p}
\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{m-q} {m\choose q} q^{m-p}
\\ =  {m\choose p} (m-p)! [z^{m-p}]     
\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{m-q} {m\choose q} \exp(qz)
\\ =  {m\choose p} (m-p)! [z^{m-p}]  (\exp(z)-1)^m.$$

Note however that  $\exp(z)-1 = z + \cdots$ and  hence when $m-p\lt m$
we get a zero value  because the coefficient vanishes.  This condition
is equivalent to  $p\gt 0$ as required.  On the  other hand when $p=0$
we get

$${m\choose 0} m! [z^m] (\exp(z)-1)^m = m!$$

as claimed.